# MySQL User_ID - Help needed

Tags: php, mysql, sql

These are my 4 MySQL tables:

```
---Users---
user_id
user_name
user_email
user_firstname
user_lastname
user_state
user_country
user_occupation
user_dob
user_accountcreationdate
user_sex
user_password

---Logins----
user_id
last_login
browser_type
ip_address

---User Roles---
user_id
role_id

---Roles---
role_id
role_name
role_description
```

When a user registers an account on the website it will create an auto increment user_id in the Users Table. How do I get the same user_id from the Users Table to Logins and User Roles Table? The user_id in each table are the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1) Insert your new user in the users table

2) Get the `user_id` by using the MySQL `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function (More info [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id))

**Example:**

```
mysql> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
        -> 195
```

3) Insert other data (and the `user_id`) into the other tables

Answer (score 1):

After you insert into the users table you can fetch the last insert id.  Or at any time you can run a select to get the id.

Comment: Is it possible to put the same user_id into all three tables at the same time? Like when the user registers, it will automatically put the user_id from the Users Table into User Roles and Logins.

Comment: You want to have one of the tables (seemingly the User table) run an auto increment to provision a new id.  If you want the database to handle inserts into the other tables as well you could use a trigger.

Comment: Be careful selecting the last inserted ID, since somebody else could come along and register before you've had chance to get the "latest" ID generated. I.e. two (or more) people registering in quick succession. Rather, use mysqli_insert_id() as I have suggested, since this will return the correct id for the current session.

Comment: How does mysqli_insert_id() return the correct id for the current session? How will it know what session it is?

Comment: Ummm, first of all I did not recommend any particular one of the scads of ways to fetch the last insert id.  Also the native MySQL function is session & table bound....

Comment: @Quickshiftin I was just commenting regarding the "run a select to get the id" bit. I didn't mean you were specifically saying use a select query, but it could be interpreted that way, so just wanted to say be careful with that.

Comment: @sk00v Fair enough I suppose.  I was trying to answer the somewhat general question from OP..; generally speaking, if you know the value of the user_name column, there's nothing preventing a SELECT for it to get the user_id and run an INSET into any of the referential tables.  Hence the 'Or' part of my answer.  A bit vague, I'll grant you that.

Comment: @pinank the function is tied to that instance of the script (unless you're doing something particularly funky) so any simultaneous connections will not affect it. Hope that helps!

Comment: @quickshiftin no worries! I think the OP has a few valid choices now. So he can pick which he prefers :)

Answer (score 1):

As you're using PHP, you can use the php command [mysql_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) (or whatever flavour you're using, such as mysqli_insert_id() etc):

```
$new_user_id = mysql_insert_id();
```

This will give you the auto-generated id from the previously executed SQL.

Comment: The mysql extension has been deprecated at this point...  http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: Yes, hence why is said "or whatever flavour you're using, such as mysqli_insert_id()" :)